# Chrome is not loading img src when set in javascript

Tags: javascript, caching, google-chrome, image

I have a photo album which cycles through a series of images when the user clicks on FORWARD or BACK, implemented by Javascript setting the src of an img. It works properly on FF, Opera, IE, and Safari, but not in Chrome - in Chrome the images sometimes appear and sometimes are blank space. It appears if the images are cached they are visible, but if they have not been loaded already Chrome does not load them. I have confirmed the src is being set correctly in the element, it just is not displaying.

If the images are loaded in the html for the page they show up properly when .src is set in javascript, but if they are not in the loaded html code then some of them will show up and some will not - but only in Chrome, in all other browsers it appears to work properly.

Is there some cache setting I need to use for Chrome, or a hack I can do to make sure these are loaded properly?

Thanks to all.

russell

(Added) Some code follows. It is generated, which is where the strange constants come from, and the file continues with a couple hundred more < li > elements

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <link href="../lame.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <TITLE>Young/Haraske slides</TITLE>
  <script src="../lame.js"></script>
  <script>

    var int2atts = [], int2path = [], paths = {}, atts;

      atts = {}

        int2atts[36] = atts;
        int2path[36] = "Families/Young/Russell"

      window.onload = function() {substituteNodeInfo(); showPage(254);}
      var imagePtr = 0;
      function nextImage(i) {

         imagePtr = (imagePtr + i + 254) % 254;
         var nextSrc = document.getElementById("photo" + imagePtr).src
         var mainImage = document.getElementById("MainImage");
         var src = mainImage.src;
         mainImage.src = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf("/")) + nextSrc.substring(nextSrc.lastIndexOf("/"));

         return false;
      }                
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY id="pathBody">
  <H1 id="pageTitle">Russell</H1>
  <div>
    <img id="MainImage" src="../pictures/1845DEC61.JPG"></img>
    <h3 id="Title">Russell</h3>
    <div id="Text"></div>

    <a href="" onclick="return nextImage(-1)">Previous</a> 
    <a href="" onclick="return nextImage(1)">Next</a>
    <p />

    This filter is included in the following paths:
    <ul class="paths">

        <li class="path"><a href="../folders/Russell.html?path=36">Families/Young/Russell</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="choosePage"></div>
  <ul id="gallery" class="filteredItems">

      <li id="listing0" class="lineblock"><p>
          <a class='folder' href="../items/1845DEC61.html">
            <img id="photo0" src='../thumbnails/1845DEC61.JPG' alt='1845DEC61.JPG'>
            <br />Image page</a>/<a href="../fullsize/1845DEC61.JPG">Full size</a>
          <br />1845DEC61.JPG
      </li>

      <li id="listing1" class="lineblock"><p>
          <a class='folder' href="../items/1669.html">
            <img id="photo1" src='../thumbnails/1669.JPG' alt='1669.JPG'>
            <br />Image page</a>/<a href="../fullsize/1669.JPG">Full size</a>
          <br />1669.JPG
      </li>
```

Comment: Could you please post some code / create a fiddle? I'm also using Chrome so I could try to reproduce it.

Comment: It sound to me as if you need to preload your images.

Comment: There are up to 1000 images, so I'd rather not preload. Probably rather than that I would drop the functionality to scroll though the pictures on this page.

Comment: Don't preload every image. Preload, say, 2 images ahead of where the user is.

Comment: How do I go about preloading them? I tried "var im = new image(); im.src = xxx.jpg, but that does the same thing. The only thing that works seems to be actually putting an IMG tag in - I could do that for all of them and set display to none, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: MooTools has a feature for this.

Comment: Is this bug still around? I am figuring exactly the same problem (2 yeras after this question here!) right now using Embedded Chromium with Xilium CefGlue C#. I am adding about 800 DIVs with IMGs dynamically. Some Images are getting loaded, some are not (Getting the broken Image Icon) No work around currently, tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache is apparently being cleared out. Network tab shows chrome thinks it is loading the image from cache, when I tried clearing cache everything worked. Possibly this is a bug, where cache is being cleaned out but the index is not updated?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: It is a reported bug in chrome, [link]http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20960

Comment: I am also facing the same problem with chrome. firefox is okey.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you may try to prefetch the image via ajax as explained in this : http://www.4thkingdom.com/public/computers/789073-web-site-speed-prefetching-images-css/view-post.html

Comment: Nice thought, but I didn't mention that the application is html, there is no server side, so I can't use Ajax. The link you gave also suggested var im = new Image();
im.src = 'http://URL_OF_IMAGE'; which I have already tried, and doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem arising from a reuse of Horizontal image scrolling  -to see page wait for 20 second so timer go down- <s>http://www.btinternet.com/~st_rise/main/mainfram.htm?../imagery/imgscroll3h.htm</s> 
with a trick from <s>[www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/javascript-sleep-function-t66049.html](http://www.btinternet.com/~st_rise/main/mainfram.htm?../imagery/imgscroll3h.htm)</s>

In my  loop of loading image I call this function that simulate sleep.

```
function pause( iMilliseconds ) {
    var sDialogScript = 'window.setTimeout( function () { window.close(); }, ' + iMilliseconds + ');';
    window.showModalDialog('javascript:document.writeln ("<script>' + sDialogScript + '<' + '/script>")');
}
```

You can see result in my site  [elenco alloggi]: http://www.unitaria.it/interventi_u.html