# img src doesn't load correctly after change, works miraculously when window is resized

Tags: javascript, css, image

I have two overlayed `divs` (let's call them *top* and *bottom*), and the visible `div` can be swapped by the user (I set `opacity = 0` on the *top* `div` to show the *bottom* one). Each has a different `img`. The user can change the images like a photo gallery, where two arrows change the `src` of both `img` using JavaScript.

The user may only click the arrows when the *top* `div` is visible.
However, sometimes after the user clicks one of the arrows (changing both images), and then hides the *top* `div`, the *bottom* `div` image doesn't show up at all. The `src` is changed with no problems, but there is no image visible.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, there is no image visible, even though DevTools shows the correct source and picture. If I change the viewport size slightly (by resizing the window, or bringing up DevTools), it magically appears. This does not always happen, sometimes the picture is shown with no issues. What is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share some of the code? Specifically how you request the images. If you are requesting the images from JS using something like `var img = new Image()` this is async, the page will still be rendered but the image may or may not be ready by the time you need it. If you have them loaded using HTML tags, then it may be that you have to wait for the content to be ready before allowing the user to flip around the gallery. Share the code and surely someone here will be able to help.

Comment: I just change the `src` using `setAttribute`, but I'm also preloading both the *next* and *previous* images in a hidden `div`, so that's not the issue.

Comment: And I just found a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119440/chrome-is-not-loading-img-src-when-set-in-javascript

Submitted 5 years ago!

Comment: I think I just solved the issue by applying a `transform: rotate(0deg);` to both divs, to force the browser to show the appropriate image. I'll test this further.